# What assembly contains the BreezeControllerAttribute?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, breeze, asp.net-web-api2

I'm just trying out Breeze.js and decided to convert an existing Web API 2.2 (.net 4.5.2) project to Breeze.  I went to NuGet and installed the Breeze.ContextProvider and Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6 packages, since I used EF6 for this project.  When I add the [BreezeController] attribute to my controllers Visual Studio (2015 CTP) doesn't know what it is ("Cannot resolve symbol 'BreezeController'" error).  So I tried installing other NuGet packages that might contain this attribute (i.e. Breeze.Server.WebApi2), but couldn't find any.  The docs don't seem to show what assembly I need to use for that attribute, so I'm stuck.  Any help for this?  Is that attribute deprecated?  I can't find any mention of it in the docs...  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The BreezeControllerAttribute class is part of the Breeze.ContextProvider assembly. ( and is available as a standalone nuget package: Breeze.Server.ContextProvider or as part of the Breeze.Server.WebApi2 nuget) Not sure why you are having this issue, but nuget can be a little flaky... It might be worth removing all nugets and reinstalling them.

Answer (score 0):

I just searched and installed "breeze.webapi2" and had the same issue. When I did a search for "breeze.server.webapi2", I noticed that that package wasn't installed (I thought it was a dependency on the "breeze.webapi2" package).
Installing just the "breeze.server.webapi2" currently doesn't do anything.
I'm doing this via VS2015 CTP6. My coworker was able to install the very same package using VS2013.